# Purpose of internal archiva "snapshot" repository?

Tags: apache, snapshot, archiva

I get what internal libraries are. But what is the purpose of a snapshot repository in archiva?

Libraries - private releases
Snapshots - private builds?

I have archiva set up and working with LDAP, but I am wondering why I need a snapshot repository. What purpose does this solve? Why is this used in development?

Also, lets say I update a library  in the internal repo. Does this automatically update in the project POM files which use Maven, or I must update those poms to use the new JAR version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually before releasing a maven project, the version is -SNAPSHOT.
So with such repositories you can share fresh SNAPHOT of your project for other people in your team to test or with a ci server.

Answer (score -1):

Snapshots is maven idea to give version number as  -SNAPSHOT , its under development it can be change any time.

Internal repository is the release repository with fixed version number. You can modify the SNAPSHOT, but That artifact never changes after it is released.

When we use internal, if dependency does not found inside it, then it will download it from central repository of maven. where as in snapshot it does not.

Comment: it's "-SNAPSHOT", not "-SNAPSHOTS"